# Firebase Cloud functions deploying all modules

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

[image]My Folder structure:

```
-functions
  -modules
  -index.js
```

In index.js, I written only required module and the exported function name.

When I'm deploying one function from module, firebase deploying the entire modules folder in google cloud console.

Is it the normal behavior or do I've to change the folder structure ?

Comment: What is the existing structure? Can you share a screenshot of it so we can see how you have declared modules?

Comment: I've attached the existing structure screenshot above.